# How did I get 35 reputation from 2 votes?

Tags: support, answers, reputation, accepted-answer

On https://askubuntu.com/a/1026404/711310, I got two upvotes and zero downvotes, but I gained 35 reputation from it. How did this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got another 15 rep because your answer was accepted. See https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation for details about reputation. The relevant bit here is:

> **You gain reputation when:**
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)

Comment: That explains it, I didn't realize it got accepted :)

Comment: @NerdOfLinux if ever in doubt about rep in the future, you can always check [your reputation page](https://askubuntu.com/users/711310/nerdoflinux?tab=reputation) which will give you the run-down of what got you what, and you'd see it says "upvote", "accept", and "upvote".  :)

Answer (score 3):

Also see https://askubuntu.com/reputation

It is a personal text based aggregated view of all your rep.

Comment: Wow, never seen this form before!